# view % of screen ios xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, alignment

How can I set the Image View on xcode within 33% of screen size,
for example, I use `android:layout_weight="1"` in android studio and
I use `style={{flex:1}}` in react native,
what can I use for ios development?

Comment: You can use an aspect ratio constraint between the screen width/height and your image view width/height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

Add following constraints:

*Required Cosntraints:*

- ImageView.height = 0.33 x MainView.height
- ImageView.width = 0.33 x MainView.width

*Optional Cosntraints:* (It helps in setting x & y position of view)

- ImageView.centerY = MainView.centerY
- ImageView.centerX = MainView.centerX

[image]

Equal Width Constraint:

[image]

Equal Height Constraint:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just get the screen height of the device by using **[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height** and get 33 percentage of that height and assign that height to imageview. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Using AutoLayout,

For Imageview apply constraints like this

```
1) equal width to parent view
2) equal height to parent view
```

then change multiplier by double clicking to the imageview,

where

```
constant - 0
priority - 1000
multiplier - 0.33
```

apply this to both constraints (equal width as well as to equal height) which will convert to proportional width and height with 33% of parent view.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done programmatically as well:

```
  let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, 
                                            y: 0, 
                                            width: self.view.frame.width * 0.33, 
                                            height: self.view.frame.height * 0.33))
```